# Populating one dataset overwrites another dataset result

Tags: c#, winforms

Its been 2-3 hours and I can't still understand why its happening. Need help.

I am populating dataGridView using dataset. There are two tables master and detail. I am using two datasets to fetch both tables from datasets (Also I've implemented class to fetch from database so I just call that class's function which return dataset containing result and I assign that to my local datasets).

Now what is happening is 1st I fetch detail table and check whether its null etc and if not I fetch second. Here the problem arises as soon second gets populated 1st one overwrites. I am so out of my mind now that I can't understand what is happening. here's my code:

```
private void txtInvNumber_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtInvNumber.Text != "")
        {
            try
            {
                DataSet dsdetail = new DataSet();
                DataTable dtdetail = new DataTable();
                string query = "SELECT sell.ItemId 'Item ID',Item 'Item Name' ,sell.Quantity ,Status ,Credit_Limit 'Credit Limit',"
                + "Total_amount 'Total Amount' ,Discount_Allowed 'Discount' ,Discounted_amount 'Discounted Amount' , "
                + "Payable_Amount 'Payable Amount',Advance 'Advance Paid',Amount_Received 'Amount Received', Amount_Receivable 'Amount Receivable' "
                + "FROM dbo.DSelling_Information sell  join Item_Infomation it on  sell.ItemId=it.Item_ID "
                + "where InvoiceNum = '" + txtInvNumber.Text + "'";

                string query_master = "select Sale_Orde_date 'Date', mp.Cust_ID,CUST_Name,Total_Quantity,Total_Amount,"
                + "Amount_Received,Amount_Receivable,Report_Status from dbo.MSelling_Information mp join dbo.Customer_Information cs on mp.Cust_ID=cs.CUST_ID"
                + " where Invoice_num = '" + txtInvNumber.Text + "'";
                dsdetail = db.func_ds(query);
                if (dsdetail != null && dsdetail.Tables != null && dsdetail.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    ds2 = db.func_ds(query_master); <--here dsitem gets populated too.
                    if (ds2 != null && ds2.Tables != null && ds2.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        dtSellDate.Value = DateTime.ParseExact(ds2.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Date"].ToString(), "M/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                        txtCustID.Text = ds2.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Cust_ID"].ToString();
                        txtCustomerName.Text = ds2.Tables[0].Rows[0]["CUST_Name"].ToString();
                        txtTotalQuantity.Text = ds2.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Total_Quantity"].ToString();
                        txtTotalAmount.Text = ds2.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Total_Amount"].ToString();
                        txtAmountRcvd.Text = ds2.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Amount_Received"].ToString();
                        txtAmountRcvble.Text = ds2.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Amount_Receivable"].ToString();
                        txtReportStatus.Text = ds2.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Report_Status"].ToString();
                        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
                        dtdetail = dsdetail.Tables[0];
                        //dataGridView1.DataSource = db.func_ds(query).Tables[0]; // dataset
                        dataGridView1.DataSource = dtdetail;

                        isDgFill = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ds1.Clear();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
            dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
            isDgFill = false;
        }
    }
```

I tried using new keyword but no luck

```
    dataGridView1.DataSource = new DataTable("dtdetail");
```

also this:

```
    dataGridView1.DataSource = new DataSet("dsdetail").Tables[0];
```

Here is another problem:
I tried direct function call on populating data:

```
    dataGridView1.DataSource = db.func_ds(query).Tables[0];
```

it worked but on cellclick i need to do multiple calculations which includes fetching data from database so whenever i fetch using dataset it just make datasource of datagridview null.

I am using different names for each dataset but nothing is happening. Please if anyone can tell where I am wrong i'll be thankful to him\her a lot.

Comment: Could it have something to do with the fact you're overriding your variable in this line or is this intended? `dtdetail = dsdetail.Tables[0];`

Comment: Its not overriding I am assigning this to dsdetail's table to dtdetail, see ds and dt difference?

Comment: Also @kha problem is not in this line but this one: `ds2 = db.func_ds(query_master);`

Comment: Ah yes. my bad. Confused the `ds` and `dt`.

Answer (score 0):

If you reassigning data source of data grid view It will clear the previous one .I think this the mistake your making.

Comment: Well I solved this problem as I declared dataset in function in class where it was populating (previously it was class member not local function), this made function return new object of dataset everytime it is being called. This modification relieved me from both problems :)